# How to get date values form grid's cell to date time picker control in new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, datetimepicker

How can we pass a **grid cell's value to datetimepicker** ?
I have a grid with columns, in which **one column store date values(YYYY-MM-DD)** format.
When I **click edit button, selected row values need to be passed to new form** and **date value is need to be set of DateTimePicker control**.
Is this possible, if yes then how ?

Comment: what you tried yet ? do post here

Comment: I've tried this code: `frmSubForm.dtpBookPublishDate.value = frmMainApplication.dgvBooksDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;`

Comment: @ gridview_RowCommand u can fetch date value and also set value or save in a variable/ session for assigning datetimepicker control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I need:

```
DateTime dtBookPublishDate = DateTime.Parse (dgvBooksDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToStrin());                                                                      
myBookInformation.dtpBookPublishDateInfo.Value = DateTime.Parse(dtBookPublishDate.ToShortDateString());
```

where, frmBookInformation is sub form and currently Im on Main Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, while your date has to be in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SetmyDate(){
    var yDate = "YYYY-MM-DD";
    var date  = yDate.substr(7,2);
    var mon   = yDate.substr(4,2);
    var year  = yDate.substr(0,4);
    $('#dateselector').datepicker(
        "setDate",
        new Date(mon + "/" + date + "/" + year)
    ); 
}   
</script>
```